# Python Sockets: Connection Timeout

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, serversocket

I'm trying to write two short python scripts that will connect two or more machines to each other, one as the server and the others as clients. It worked perfectly when testing the client and the server script on the same computer, but when I tried it from another computer the client kept timing out; it couldn't connect to the server. Here's my server code:

```
import socket
server = socket.socket()
host = "computername"
port = 12345
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(5)

client, addr = server.accept()
```

Client code:

```
import socket
server = socket.socket()
host = "computername"
port = 12345
server.connect((host, port))
```

Any clue as to why the machines can't connect?

Comment: have you tried to disable firewall (on both computers)? Do you have a [public ip](http://superuser.com/q/165986/13868) on the server? What happens if you run `python3 -mhttp.server --bind computername 12345` as a server and `python3 -c "from urllib.request import urlopen; print(urlopen('http://computer:12345').read().decode())"` as a client?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian How does that code work? I don't understand what to do with it.

Comment: copy-paste these commands into the command-line (terminal, console) on the corresponding computers (first the http server, then the client that makes the request). The purpose is to find out whether the issue is your code or the network. If the request is successful then the issue is your code. If the request fails then the issue has nothing to do with your Python code and you should configure the network first.

Comment: I get an error saying "There is no module named request" from the client end, and "there is no module named http" from the server.

Comment: it means that you use Python 2 ([edit] your question and mention that you use Python 2). Notice `python3` (there is `3` at the end in the commands that I've suggested). On Python 2, you could run: `python2 -mSimpleHTTPServer 12345` as the server and `python2 -c "from urllib2 import urlopen; print urlopen('http://computername:12345').read()"` as the client.

Comment: It worked, and I got the request. However, from what I've heard my original code is working. Do you have any suggestions on how to change what I have so it will work?

Comment: If the commands that I've provided work then your network and firewall settings are ok and the issue is your *actual* code. If `host=""` in the server code doesn't fix the issue then post your *actual* code that you use: [create a *minimal complete* code example that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and update your question

Comment: Well, the commands worked from my individual machine. I have as of yet to test it with two machines.

Comment: there is no point, to run them on the same machine. To test the network, there has to be a network to test between the server and the client. [Reread what the purpose of running them is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686650/python-sockets-connection-timeout#comment55173455_33686650)

Comment: Network problem; the command timed out. Sorry I didn't test them over two machines the first time. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are changing host variable properly when running both client and server scripts in different machines. Try by changing that properly/or using IP address of server machine.

Comment: No, the host variable is the same; it's the name of my computer. I'll try using IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The communication could be prohibited by a firewall.

To rule out DNS related problem, try IPs instead of hostnames:

```
# server: listen on all interfaces
server.bind(('', port))
```

and:

```
# client: specify server's IP address
server.connect(("192.168.XX.YY", port))
```

with a real IP address, of course.

Comment: Using IP addresses didn't "address" the problem. I'm still timing out. I'll try a few other things, like verifying the IP address, but there's not much that I can do at that point. My code should work, right?

Comment: @I.A.S. In this case the most probable explanation is a firewall on the server.

Comment: Would it be one particular part of the firewall or the whole thing?

Comment: I disabled the firewall, but the connection still times out. Does it have something to do with the client being a Macbook by any chance? I'm getting kind of desperate.

Comment: It's difficult to guess what's going on on a remote network. I would read the logs and probably use tcpdump to see the traffic on tcp port 12345. But that's off-topic discussion. I see no error in your code, however only the connection establishment part is shown.

Comment: The connection establishment is the part I'm concerned with; the part that I couldn't figure out. The rest was just sending and receiving text.

Comment: I also get the same problem just trying to connect to a web server, like google.com. 'code' (socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com"), 12345))) 'code'